# unable to change the swagger UI path

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am creating API documentation for a spring boot 2 microservices using Swagger and I am  new to Swagger. My spring boot app is has  context path /api/user/ So the app is accessible at localhost:8080/api/user . The swagger default ui is accessible at /swagger-ui.html . So fro my project the url turns out to be localhost:8080/api/user/swagger-ui.html/ But im am getting error

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "swagger-ui.html"
```

as there is an api localhost:8080/api/user/{id}. I cannot change the contact path of the microservices. Kindly advise how to add custom path to the swagger ui so that swagger ui is accessible at url localhost:8080/api/user/swagger/swagger-ui.html or localhosr:8080/swagger/swagger-ui.html. Below is my config file

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration{

    //...

    
      @Bean
      public Docket api(ServletContext servletContext) {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()))
            .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
      }

      private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*")).build();
      }

      private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        final AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[]{authorizationScope};
        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("Bearer", authorizationScopes));
      }

      private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("Bearer", "Authorization", "header");
      }
      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the wrong URL.

Swagger-UI is available at:

```
 http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

If you want the configure the path you can change it in application.yml (example):

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /documentation/swagger-ui-my-project.html
```

Tutorial with swagger setting if need more info: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-swagger-3-openapi-3-security-exampleba